# Reverse proxy apache to weblogic problem

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, weblogic

I have apache 2.2 server and welogic 11g running on web server. Apache is set for revers proxy on port 8080, weblogic serves two web pages and it's on port :7001 
first page:
localhost:7001/e-SPP/app
second page:
localhost:7001/e-sprejem/app

I would like to access this two pages with apache like so:
localhost:8080/e-SPP/app
localhost:8080/e-sprejem/app

```
Listen 8080
ServerName localhost:8080
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
RewriteEngine On

<Location /e-SPP/app>
   ProxyPass localhost:7001/e-SPP/app
   ProxyPassReverse  localhost:7001/e-SPP/app
</Location>

<Location /e-sprejem/app>
 ProxyPass localhost:7001/e-sprejem/app
 ProxyPassReverse  localhost:7001/e-sprejem/app
</Location>
```

This configuration opens my pages bust it's black anw white because CSS and JS aren't loaded!
Path to the css over proxy looks like this :

```
localhost:8080/e-SPP/css/style.css
```

which doesn't open the CSS if I change the port to 7001 the it works !!!

```
localhost:7001/e-SPP/css/style.css
```

What should I do that CSS and JS are loaded?

Interesting is favicon which is being  loaded 
      http://localhost:8080/e-SPP/images/new/favicon.gif

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reverse proxy module does not touch the content / the HTML of the page. However, most of the time you need to do this, to fix embedded absolut URLs like in your case.

My solution is to install another module to apache ( http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/ ) and let it do this rewriting. Please have a look at the projects website for some tutorials and documentation.

(My experience only comes from internal websites without a lot of traffic, so this might not always be the correct solution).